Unable to start jhipster microservice + gateway application. version 8.7.1
I'm trying to do microservices, but I'm unable to get the gateawy or the microservices healht on consul.
So I tried one of the samples: the microservices-blog-store.jh (https://github.com/jhipster/jdl-samples/blob/v8/microservice-ecommerce-store.jdl)
All the docker services are up, but when I start the gateway and microservice, I am able to login, but unable to create any Entity.
Both services are unheatlh at consul.
Looking the log of the ./mvnw at gateway. I've seen these strange bits:
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.DependencyConvergence failed with message:
Failed while enforcing releasability.

Dependency convergence error for org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.14 paths to dependency are:
+-com.okta.developer.gateway:gateway:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:jar:3.3.4:compile
    +-org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:5.3.4:compile
      +-org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:jar:8.13.4:compile
        +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.14:compile
and
+-com.okta.developer.gateway:gateway:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-config:jar:4.1.2:compile
    +-org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul:jar:4.1.2:compile
      +-com.ecwid.consul:consul-api:jar:1.4.5:compile
        +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.5:runtime
and
+-com.okta.developer.gateway:gateway:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-config:jar:4.1.2:compile
    +-org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul:jar:4.1.2:compile
      +-org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.14:compile


**A dependency conflict between spring projects??? It seem they are looking for differente versions of httpclient (4.5.14 and 4.5.5)
**
And this:
2024-10-12T10:07:21.278-03:00 DEBUG 29630 --- [  restartedMain] java.lang.ProcessBuilder                 : ProcessBuilder.start(): pid: 29651, dir: null, cmd: "docker" 

java.lang.RuntimeException: ProcessBuilder.start() debug
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1147)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1089)
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.ProcessRunner.startProcess(ProcessRunner.java:105)
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCli.run(DockerCli.java:80)
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DefaultDockerCompose.lambda$new$0(DefaultDockerCompose.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerHost.fromCurrentContext(DockerHost.java:102)
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerHost.get(DockerHost.java:88)
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerHost.get(DockerHost.java:73)
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DefaultDockerCompose.<init>(DefaultDockerCompose.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCompose.get(DockerCompose.java:93)
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeLifecycleManager.getDockerCompose(DockerComposeLifecycleManager.java:156)
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeLifecycleManager.start(DockerComposeLifecycleManager.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeListener.onApplicationEvent(DockerComposeListener.java:53)
        at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeListener.onApplicationEvent(DockerComposeListener.java:35)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:185)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:178)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:156)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextLoaded(EventPublishingRunListener.java:98)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$contextLoaded$4(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextLoaded(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:433)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
        at com.okta.developer.gateway.GatewayApp.main(GatewayApp.java:70)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)

Is it trying to start a docker???
As a sample project, I was expecting it would start without any problems.

Yes, you need Docker installed if you're using a database or OAuth.
